# Contagem cumulativa por mês

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Estou com dificuldade para fazer uma contagem cumulativa no mysql. Preciso contar a quantidade de cadastro ativo acumulado em cada mês.

Tabela:

```
id | data_cadastro | data_exclusao
---+---------------+--------------
1  | 2018-07-01    | null
2  | 2018-07-02    | 2018-08-01
3  | 2018-08-01    | null
4  | 2018-08-02    | null
5  | 2018-08-03    | null
```

O que estou buscando que o select retorne esse 'total' por mês_ano:

```
mes_ano | total   |   Descrição (só para entendimento...)
--------+-------  |  -------------------------------
2018-07 | 2       |   No mês 07 haviam 02 cadastros ativos (o id 2 foi excluído só no mês 08, então ele conta para o mês 07);
2018-08 | 4       |   No mês 08 haviam 04 (03 cadastros do mês 08 não excluídos + 01 cadastro ativo do mês 07);
```

Com a ajuda de outras questões aqui do fórum eu cheguei na contagem mensal (não cumulativa e sem tirar as exclusões) assim:

```
SELECT 
  DATE_FORMAT(data_cadastro,'%Y-%m') AS 'mes_ano',
  COUNT(id) AS 'total'
FROM cadastro
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(data_cadastro,'%Y-%m')
```

Estou na dúvida se é possível fazer esse critério direto no SELECT ou levo a consulta completa para o PHP e trato as informações por lá mesmo (não sei o que é melhor para a performance também)... Se alguém souber me ajudar. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opa,

Tenho uma sugestão para tentar resolver seu problema, porém não sou familiarizado com a sintaxe de MySQL (pesquisei no google as funções certas, porém não pude testá-las). Vou escrever o código abaixo , explicar o porquê e você efetua as possíveis adaptações e correções pra rodar certinho no seu SGBD.

Se você rodar o select sem a parte do count, o resultado serão os meses, certo?

```
SELECT 
  DATE_FORMAT(data_cadastro,'%Y-%m') AS 'mes_ano'
 FROM cadastro
 GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(data_cadastro,'%Y-%m')
```

Então, a ideia é fazer um subselect com o count e comparar as datas conforme a listagem do select externo. Os critérios são : A data_cadastro devem ser iguais (mês/ano) e a data de exclusão (mes/ano) OU é nula (ids 1,3,4,5) OU é maior que a de cadastro (id 2, data_exclusao mês/ano, 08/2018, é maior que a data_cadastro mês/ano, 07/2018).

```
   SELECT 
  DATE_FORMAT(c1.data_cadastro,'%Y-%m') AS 'mes_ano',
 (select count(id)
    from cadastro as c2
  where DATE_FORMAT(c1.data_cadastro,'%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(c2.data_cadastro,'%Y-%m')
     and (c2.data_exclusao is null or 
         DATE_FORMAT(c2.data_exclusao,'%Y-%m') 
       > DATE_FORMAT(c2.data_cadastro,'%Y-%m'))
       ) as total    
 FROM cadastro as c1
 GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(c1.data_cadastro,'%Y-%m')
```

Quanto à dúvida sobre performance, não sei dizer... creio ser mais performático e simples realizar a consulta direto no banco, mas é palpite e opinião pessoal. Se alguém tiver algo a contribuir sobre esse ponto será de grande ajuda.

Boa sorte!

Comment: Obrigado, MarceloBambino! Funcionou como eu precisava. Vou estudar mais sobre subselect. Eu só precisei fazer um ajuste no código (>=), de: `where DATE_FORMAT(c1.data_cadastro,'%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(c2.data_cadastro,'%Y-%m')` para: `where DATE_FORMAT(c1.data_cadastro,'%Y-%m') >= DATE_FORMAT(c2.data_cadastro,'%Y-%m')`.

Comment: Opa, show de bola que funcionou. Obrigado pelo retorno!